# Click twice to set params on url - angular

Tags: angularjs, http, browser

when I enter to my url:

```
wwww.y.com/page#
```

I adding manually "?test" so the url will be:

```
wwww.y.com/page#?test
```

But its take affects only after I click twice(not double click)- on the browser address bar ( happens in each systems/browser)  - its not refresh my page.

Note that i use location.url to take the params from the url

Comment: Is that really a question about **programming**?

Comment: I don't know if its angular or browser  issue